# How to mutate a dataset using an arithmetical expression in R in shinyR

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to create an a shiny app, which accepts  formula as an input parameter and mutate the file accordingly.

But I am not able to it and the result is wither printing the formula. Appreciate if anyone could look into the issue and suggest a solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

 ui <- pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel = headerPanel('data'),
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(#         fileInput(
            #         'mtcars', h4('Uplaodmtcardata in csv format')
            # ),
            uiOutput('formula')),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("data"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    mtcarsFile <- reactive({
            input$mtcars
    })


    xxmtcars <-
            reactive({
                    as.data.table(mtcars)
            })



    output$formula <- renderUI({
            textInput('formula',
                      h5('formula'))

    })
    formulaPars <- reactive({
            !!(input$formula)
    })

    newCol  = reactive({
            quo(formulaPars())
    })

    output$data <- renderDataTable({
            as.data.table(mutate(xxmtcars(), cyl + (!!newCol())))


    })

}

 runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be changed like the following by using `rlang::parse_expr()` to get the desired output:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mtcarsFile <- reactive({
    input$mtcars
  })

  xxmtcars <-
    reactive({
      if (!is.null(input$mtcars)) {
        as.data.table(read.csv(input$mtcars$datapath))
      } 
  })

  output$formula <- renderUI({
    textInput('formula',  h5('formula'))

  })

  formulaPars <- reactive({
    (input$formula)
  })

  newCol  = reactive({
    formula = formulaPars()
    if (formula != '') {
      rlang::parse_expr(formula)
    }
  })

  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    data <- xxmtcars()
    if (!is.null(data) && input$formula != '') {
      as.data.table(mutate(data , cyl + !!newCol()))
    }
  })  
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing..Thank you very much for your help.It is working.